# how to split a input model string value and store the values as seperate properties in model object

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a form with multiple currency value inputfields and I have a directive which restricts the currency value to be entered as something like space for example USD 100.But I need to split the model value and seperate the currency and number and store it in the same model object.
So , USD 100 can be splitted into, USD , 100 as integer

```
$scope.formData = {
  Fee : "USD 100"
 }
```

this should become as

```
 $scope.formData = {
 fee : 100,
 feeCurrency : USD
 }
```

there are multiple fields in the form along with other type of data also.Please help me with any thoughts where I can implement this with service or directive so that I can easily apply to all the similar fields.

Comment: Is it always going to be `Fee` => `fee` and `feeCurrency`?

Comment: its just an example , there are several fields with different names where user had to enter USD 100 format.Yeah , always going to be Currency appended to the field name  fee => fee and feeCurrency.please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way you could do it with a directive. I've made a lot of assumptions here and this is not production worthy code, but it should give you a base to start from. Basically you pass the object to the directive and then watch a property on that object for changes. When the property changes you can split on a space character and fill in the appropriate values on the object. Since it's a directive you can use it anywhere.

*js*

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.feeData = {
            fee: 0,
            feeCurrency: 'N/A',
            value: ''
        };
    })
    .directive('feeDirective', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                feeData: '='
            },
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.$watch('feeData.value', function(newValue, oldValue) {
                    console.log(newValue);
                    var data = newValue.split(' ');
                    if (data.length === 2) {
                        console.log(data);
                        scope.feeData.fee = data[0];
                        scope.feeData.feeCurrency = data[1];
                    }
                }, true);
            }
        }
    });
```

*html*

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <div>
        <input type="text" ng-model="feeData.value" fee-directive fee-data="feeData">
    </div>
    <div>
        Value: {{feeData.value}}
        <br/> Fee: {{feeData.fee}}
        <br/> Currency: {{feeData.feeCurrency}}
    </div>
</div>
```

[Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9q5npoLq/) that illustrates the above code.

Comment: thanks for the response  @Lex , can you please suggest if I can pass the input element model name too to make it more generic ??

Comment: @SanthoshkiranGudla You can get it from the `attrs` collection that is passed to the `link` function. `attrs.ngModel`. If you need access to the actual object then add `require: 'ngModel'` to the directive and then `ngModel` as a fourth parameter to the `link` function and you'll have full access to the object so you can check validity, etc.

Comment: thanks for that, but I m thinking to  reuse the forms to load the data from server which includes two seperate values and I need to combine the currency code and number to display to the user in the single existing field as "USD 100", is there a way to do this within the same directive both the operations